# Android Studio display localized value in spinner but get only corresponding english value

Tags: android, localization

1. I have an Android App which should support Multi languages.
2. I have two string.xml files one supporting english language and the other one supporting my local language.
3. I have displayed a string array from the resources file into a spinner
   then the selected value by the user should be compared with the value in the database server.
4. In the database server the values are stored in english language only. So, there is an issue in comparision
5. So, irrespective of the display language in spinner, in the java code, I should be able to get the corresponding english value only.

I am trying to create separate string arrays in Java code. But I think there would be a simpler solution.

Your help is appreciated!